# mirroring gitlab repo on to gerrit

Tags: gitlab, version-control, gerrit

we are trying to setup mirror for repo which is there in gitlab onto gerrit. but in all the references I see only replication/mirroring from gerrit to gitlab using plugin     [https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/plugins/replication/Documentation/index.html#replication-of-account-data-notedb](https://%5D) is there any plugin here we can use?

I have implemented through a pipeline where it clones from gitlab and pushes to gerrit, but wanted to know is there any other better way